# Call class extended from AndroidApplication class

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I have a simple activity and I want to call that class:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {


@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    startApp();
}

public void startApp(){
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new MyGdxGame(), config);
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What is `AndroidApplication ` ?

Comment: Yes you can. Just do `AndroidLauncher.startApp()`

Comment: @Shark startApp is not a static method so this is not right. 
What OP is asking, is in fact possible, but you will need to declare that class in the manifest under the <application> tag as android:name="yourpackage.AndroidLauncher"